# Проблемы с строковой переменной

Tags: python, python-3.x

Что я делаю не так почему он выводить `False`

code:

```
a = str(input("HexCode>"))
#6b 6f 6d 62 61 74 0a
if a in " ":
    print(True)
    a = a.replace(" ",'')
    print(a)
else:
    print(False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a in " "` означает «Строка "6b 6f 6d 62 61 74 0a" содержится в строке " "». Что очевидно ложно. Если вы хотите проверить наличие пробелов во введённой строке, то нужно операнды поменять местами: `" " in a`.

Comment: Условие звучит примерно так если в строке есть пробел то его нужно убрать(заменить)

Comment: Ну, тогда я вам дал правильный ответ.

Comment: Точно,спасибо !